# VBA How to generate the name of an option button dynamically?

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button

VBA I need to generate the name of an option button dynamically.  The option button is a Forms Control option button on a user form.I have the following code in a module, not in the behind code on a user form

```
        Sub Test_Form()

            Dim MyOptionButton As String
            Dim OptionButton As String
            Dim i As Integer

       i = 1

            MyOptionButton = OptionButton & i
            'I'm hoping the compiler will understand this as "OptionButton1"

            If Range("C2").Value = 5 Then
                MyOptionButton.Value = True
               'Error message here:  "invalid qualifier"

            End If

    frmTest_Form.Show
End Sub
```

It appears that the compiler needs to have control name as "OptionButton1" predefined, and does not read MyOptionButton as "OptionButton1".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where is the option button you're trying to address?  On a worksheet?  What type of optionbutton is it - Forms, or ActiveX?

Comment: You will most likely have to find an alternative, like using the `Tag` property, and having a function that searches through the controls for that `Tag` instead of the `Name`,

Comment: `MyOptionButton = "OptionButton" & i` then you need to index into something like `ActiveSheet.Shapes()` using that name

Comment: The option button is a Forms Control button on a user form.

Comment: Your option button ia string, not as a control, please try controls(myopt button).value

Comment: And you can create optionbutton array in vba I think

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I don't have it working yet.

Comment: `Me.Controls("OptionButton" & i).Value = True` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Your question implies you want to change the name of an option button, but that is not what your code indicates you want to do. Your code appears to simply make the option button true if the value in a cell equals 5. You should consider making it false if the value isn't 5.

You get at the option button by referring to it from the Controls collection of the user form.

You need to qualify which sheet the range is on -  if you don't it will be the active sheet which may not always be the sheet you expect; it would also be better if you qualified which workbook as well. I assumed the workbook your code is in (ThisWorkbook).

It is better practice to not work off of the default instance of a user form; declare a variable As the form you want to use and then New it up.

Using an underscore in object names isn't good practice. Underscores separate an object from its events (e.g. CommandButton1_Click). I removed the underscore from the user form's name.

```
Dim myForm As frmTestForm
Set myForm = New frmTestForm
Dim myOptButton As Control
Set myOptButton = myForm.Controls("OptionButton1")
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet").Range("C2").Value = 5 Then
    myOptButton.Value = True
Else
    myOptButton.Value = False
End If
```

Comment: Yes, Smiley!  That worked great!  Thanks for guidance on style as well.

Comment: The use of the word "generate" in the question `was a bad choice.  "Access" would have been better.   The project is to turn a button on a user form on if the right value is found in the cell.